# flutter: bottomSheet dragable and animated

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

I'm working on an application where I want to display a bottomSheet when user clicked on a button to display more information like the following example

here's an example: https://i.ibb.co/7bjgNRg/example.gif

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to open the example link provided, so following is the in general way of implementing a bottomSheet on click of a button.

**Step 1 : Create a Function to Show Bottom Sheet**

```
void _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('More Information'),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

**Step 2 : Create the button that will trigger the display of the bottom sheet on screen**

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Appbar'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _showBottomSheet(context);
          },
          child: Text('Show More Information'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can customize the appearance and contents of the bottom sheet by modifying the widgets inside the builder function of showModalBottomSheet.

Comment: this is not the problem I already implemented the bottomSheet the problem is I want an animation and the bottomSheet to be dragable like the example int the GIF.